# Using Scipy.optimize.linprog for the first time in Python

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

Hello,

I'm using Scipy.optimize.linprog for the first time.

My problem is this:

I don't know how to use the code, but these are the variables I am trying to optimize:

```
    Date        Salary  Name               Team    y_pred
    0           1       2                  3        4
63  2017-12-02   8600   Andre Drummond     24      [0.134405]
219 2017-12-02   6900   Khris Middleton    22      [0.130379]
193 2017-12-02  11600   Giannis Ante       22      [0.121447]
133 2017-12-02  10400   DeMarcus Cousins   11      [0.119983]
 30 2017-12-02  11400   LeBron James        4      [0.118579]
162 2017-12-02   7500   Devin Booker       15      [0.112879]
102 2017-12-02   7000   Jusuf Nurkic        6      [0.11069]
 94 2017-12-02   6300   Brandon Ingram     16      [0.1035]
 61 2017-12-02   8600   Nikola Jokic        9      [0.100618]
 11 2017-12-02   6600   Lonzo Ball         16      [0.0972403]
 64 2017-12-02   5900   Robert Covington   27      [0.0968286]
166 2017-12-02   8900   Damian Lillard      6      [0.0922509]
 70 2017-12-02   7000   Spencer Dinwiddie  29      [0.0917086]
152 2017-12-02   7700   Kevin Love          4      [0.0909792]
 83 2017-12-02   9900   Anthony Davis      11      [0.0860487]
 88 2017-12-02   5000   Brook Lopez        16      [0.0854736]
 25 2017-12-02   6000   Jrue Holiday       11      [0.085107]
190 2017-12-02   4900   Jordan Clarkson    16      [0.084582]
144 2017-12-02   7900   Marc Gasol         12      [0.0834062]
 65 2017-12-02   9600   Ben Simmons        27      [0.0822223]
156 2017-12-02   3500   Jameer Nelson      11      [0.0813844]
 36 2017-12-02   6000   Kent Bazemore      21      [0.0799453]
  4 2017-12-02   4600   Alex Len           15      [0.0765753]
 99 2017-12-02   5100   Julius Randle      16      [0.0755844]
 73 2017-12-02   6400   Tobias Harris      24      [0.0739983]
```

I need to have 8 players with a total maximum Salary of 50,000. It should be optimized by y_pred.

The results would be the 8 players who have the highest y_pred score and stay under 50,000.

I was able to import linprog with this code:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
```

I tried this, but, again, I'm unfamiliar with the code:

```
optimize.linprog(y_pred, nba2017test['DK Sal'], bounds=(0, 50000))
```

I got the following error:

```
all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Update:

Found this code which which works perfectly with what I was trying to do (get the 8 best players in a DraftKings Lineup):

```
from pydfs_lineup_optimizer import Site, Sport, get_optimizer


optimizer = get_optimizer(Site.DRAFTKINGS, Sport.BASKETBALL)
optimizer.load_players_from_CSV("name of csv")
lineup_generator = optimizer.optimize(8)
for lineup in lineup_generator:
    print(lineup)
```

Comment: (1) That's a knapsack-like problem (2) It's NP-hard (3) It can't be solved with LP, only with Mixed-integer programming (4) scipy's linprog is LP only (5) Your usage of linprog is way off (did you make yourself familar with the problem-form it's solving?). The 50k will never be bounds, but a RHS of some constraint. But again: linprog can't solve it.

Comment: How would you solve this problem, then Sascha? I was trying to use LP Solve, but was having problems with it interfacing with Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any MIP-capable framework and solver will do. Coin-ORs pulp (bringing Cbc solver), lpsolve, glpk, ... pulp is the one with the easiest setup and the doc-examples should be enough to tackle this task here. It's a pretty basic MIP-task. General idea: one binary for each player where b=1 -> selected; b*x the obj; sum b=8.I favor the style of cvxpy, but it's much harder to setup (when a good MIP-solver is needed), so i'm not much into presenting a pulp-based solution. If you are not able to do it, edit your question to produce code we can run too. Then someone will probably show you some solution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll take a look at pulp.

Comment: Installed pulp. Going to check out the instructions

Comment: Found this code and adjusted my question, so I'm all set! Thanks again.

Comment: It's also using pulp and MIP (not sure if you checked it), so you can have a look at the code.

Comment: Cool. I'll take a look.